# Mensagem de login inválido aparece sempre no CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Quando entro para a minha página de login, aparece logo a mensagem de aviso a dizer que o utilizador ou a passwords estão inválidos, mas isso devia só aparecer depois de carregar no botão para fazer login. Não dá para contornar isto?

Minha view:

```
    <div class="large-4 columns" style="margin-left: 15px;">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="users form">
       <span class="login_form">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?></span>
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button'));?>
</div>
</div>
```

Minha action:
          public function login() {

```
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username ou password inválidos!'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com Cakephp, mas parece-me que ele está a fazer logo submit quando carrega a página, e como os campos estão vazios e o utilizador é inválido dá erro. Agora, dar-te uma solução não consigo :/

Comment: eu também acho isso, mas não sei porque está a fazer o submit logo. Não tem lógica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É porque a sua action está tentando autenticar assim que carrega.

```
// Verifica o tipo de requisição, se for POST(form submit) tenta logar.
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username ou password inválidos!'));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ricardo Costa, esta resposta atendeu a pergunta?

Comment: Valeu Marcelo. Sim, funcionou!

Comment: @RicardoCosta marca "aceitar resposta" para finalizar a questão por favor... ;)

Comment: odne faço isso?

Comment: No canto superior esquerdo da resposta, aonde está o número 4, você passa o mouse mais abaixo e clica no "vezinho" verde.